# Jquery appending on item second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function where I am filling out rows in a table, and this is how I do it:

```
present_item = $("#approval_table").append("<tr class='approvalRow'></tr>");
approvebutton = present_item.append("present_item.append("<td class='tableItem'>"+ approvalList[itemIndex][rowsToApprove[attributeIndex]] +"</td>");");
```

This does not appear to append on to the table row, why not? How do I do this

Comment: Why did you quote `present_item.append(`?

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error because of incorrect quoting on the second line. Is that how your code really is, or a copying error here?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because `$(table).append(tr)` returns `table` not `tr`, you'd have to store that somewhere to get a reference

```
var tr = $('<tr />', {
    'class' : 'approvalRow'
});

var td = $('<td />', {
    'class' : 'tableItem',
    text    : approvalList[itemIndex][rowsToApprove[attributeIndex]]
});

$("#approval_table").append( tr.append( td ) );
```

Note that it's generally better to build the elements first, then append to the DOM once.

Comment: You could also reverse the order and use `appendTo`.

Comment: @Barmar - true, `appendTo` would return the inserted element

Answer (score 0):

First build a jQuery object for the table row, then append that to the table, then build a jQuery object for the table cell, then append that to the table row.

```
present_item = $("<tr class='approvalRow'></tr>");
$("#approval_table").append(present_item);
approvebutton = $("<td class='tableItem'>" + approvalList[itemIndex][rowsToApprove[attributeIndex]] + "</td>");
present_item.append(approvebutton);
```